# Nested routing in react-router-dom V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I hope All you are doing well. Recently I have done the project with react and make a sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bash-8zh7g?file=/src/Main.js). The problem is in routing. I want to display the child route under its parent but unfortunately I did not make it. I would be truly appreciated it, If anyone can explain the issue or fix the code.

App

```
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";
import Main from "./Main";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/main" element={<Main />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Main

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Outlet,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Child1 from "./Child1";
import Child2 from "./Child2";

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>main page</h1>
      <Link to="/main/child1">child 1</Link>||||
      <Link to="/main/child2">child 2</Link> ||||
      <Link to="/">log out</Link>
      <Outlet />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/main/child1" element={<Child1 />} />
        <Route path="/main/child1" element={<Child2 />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

child 1 & 2

```
export default function Child1() {
  return <div>Child1</div>;
}
```

```
export default function Child2() {
  return <div>Child2</div>;
}
```

Bests.

Comment: Perhaps a good read on this topic: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Issue

The main issue is that your root path matcher is specified in such a way as to not match the nested paths so the `Main` component is unmounted.

## Solution

App

Here the path for `Main` should specify a wildcard matcher to allow continued matching of sub-routes, `path="/main/*"`.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/main/*" element={<Main />} /> // <-- allow sub-route matches
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Main

Note that all the links and paths have also been updated to be relative links/paths versus absolute.

```
export default function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>main page</h1>
      <Link to="child1">child 1</Link> ||||{" "}
      <Link to="child2">child 2</Link> ||||{" "}
      <Link to="/">log out</Link>
      <Outlet />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="child1" element={<Child1 />} />
        <Route path="child2" element={<Child2 />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nested-routing-in-react-router-dom-v6]

Comment: What if within Main, you wanted to return another component if the path was `/main`. I have a similar situation where above the Child1 Route, I have `/` trying to return another component but I can't get it to render. Can this be done within the Main component?

Comment: @Steve Certainly. Specify a `path="/"` or render as an index route for what you want to render when the path is exactly `"/main"`. https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routing-in-react-router-dom-v6-forked-lfubn?file=/src/Main.js

Comment: Thanks Drew, I had a `/*` private route which renders outlet, Then a I had to put `*` in its child Route which renders `<Home/>`, then the home component returns the different routes, using `index` for that sub-root route.