# is there a way to nest routes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I was wondering if there is a way to nest routes in react in that `Navbar` is to become the parent component of dashboard and properties

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
    <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup />} />
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div>
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='/properties' element={<Dashboard />} />                        
      </div>               
    </div>              
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Just like you would do in Vue router

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/user/:id',
    component: User,
    children: [
      {
        // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
        // when /user/:id/profile is matched
        path: 'profile',
        component: UserProfile,
      },
      {
        // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
        // when /user/:id/posts is matched
        path: 'posts',
        component: UserPosts,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: literally first search result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69988285/nested-routing-in-react-router-dom-v6

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski Not quite a duplicate... that question/answer uses descendent routes instead of nesting the `Route` component. It's a subtle distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create a layout route that renders the `Navbar` component ***and*** an `Outlet` for nested routes.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavbarLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

export default NavbarLayout;
```

...

```
import NavbarLayout from '../path/to/NavbarLayout';

...

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
    <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup />} />
    <Route element={<NavbarLayout />}>
      <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path='/properties' element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

If you wanted to achieve the same thing using a routes config object:

```
const appRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: "/signup",
    element: <Signup />,
  },
  {
    element: <NavbarLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/dashboard",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: "/properties",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

...

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import appRoutes from '../path/to/appRoutes';

...

const routes = useRoutes(appRoutes);

...

return (
  ...
  {routes}
  ...
);
```

Documentation:

- [Layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes)
- [useRoutes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you are using React Router v6 the newest one. You can do it like this.

```js
<Route path='/user/:id'>
  <Route path='/profile' element={<UserProfile />}
  <Route path='/posts' element={<UserPosts />}
</Route>
```

This means that when you go to /user/1ans5us/profile it will render the UserProfile for the user with the id of '1ans5us'