# Nested child route match instead first route in react-router-dom V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need some help with react-router-dom route match in V6.

I have to match nearest child path instead first path so we can show same list page component for detail page.

```
<Route element={<PrimaryProductLayout />}>
    <Route path='primary-products' element={<ProductList />}/>
    <Route path='product/:id' element={<ProductDetail />}/>
</Route>

<Route element={<SecondaryProductLayout />}>
    <Route path='secondary-products' element={<ProductList />}/>
    <Route path='product/:id' element={<ProductDetail />}/>
</Route>
```

We have to match `PrimaryProductLayout` if we navigate from `primary-products` and same for `secondary-products`.

The reason for this is the layout have filter which we have to show in detail page with filtered data. Also need to clear filtered data if we navigate to different path.

Different approach for this problem is also useful.

I have tried to explain my problem with some sample scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested routing in react-router-dom V6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69988285/nested-routing-in-react-router-dom-v6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two routes that match by the same path, the first one specified will be the one that's rendered. If user navigates from `"/secondary-products"` where `SecondaryProductLayout` is rendered to `"/product/:id"` then the first `path='product/:id'` route is matched and the layout switches to `PrimaryProductLayout`.

You necessarily need to differentiate the product paths.

Examples:

```
<Route element={<PrimaryProductLayout />}>
  <Route path="primary-products" element={<ProductList />}/>
  <Route path="primary-products/:id" element={<ProductDetail />}/>
</Route>
<Route element={<SecondaryProductLayout />}>
  <Route path="secondary-products" element={<ProductList />}/>
  <Route path="secondary-products/:id" element={<ProductDetail />}/>
</Route>
```

```
<Route path="primary-products" element={<PrimaryProductLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<ProductList />}/>
  <Route path=":id" element={<ProductDetail />}/>
</Route>
<Route path="secondary-products" element={<SecondaryProductLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<ProductList />}/>
  <Route path=":id" element={<ProductDetail />}/>
</Route>
```

You could also create a new layout route that uses a primary/secondary path segment and renders the correct layout route component. This is to make the code a little more ***DRY***.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductLayout = () => {
  const { product } = useParams();

  switch (product) {
    case "primary-products":
    default:
      return <PrimaryProductLayout />;

    case "secondary-products":
      return <SecondaryProductLayout />;
  }
};
```

```
<Route path=":product" element={<ProductLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<ProductList />} />
  <Route path=":id" element={<ProductDetail />} />
</Route>
```

[image: Edit nested-child-route-match-instead-first-route-in-react-router-dom-v6]

Comment: Hi, Drew Reese thanks for reply.. you answer helped me to solve my problem...